# Baked apple that was left out overnight?

Tags: food-safety, apples

I made a baked apple recipe with a crumb stuffing ([recipe here](http://www.happilyhectic.com/2012/12/inside-out-apple-crisp)), and then accidentally left one of them out in the dish overnight. Is it safe to eat? (Checked stilltasty.com, my reference for such things, and couldn't find it)

Comment: I'm sure that somebody will come along and argue the point, but I wouldn't hesitate to eat or even serve that apple. There is nothing in that recipe that can't be left at room temperature for quite a bit longer than "overnight". Take apple pies for instance. A lot of people (including myself) never refrigerate them, they eat them over the course of a few days having never refrigerated them.

Comment: Yeah- since there is no dairy in the recipe, it should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not an exact match, [Still Tasty](http://www.stilltasty.com/articles/view/37) indicates up to 2 days for an apple pie at room temperature; one would expect the baked apple to have similar properties.

So yes, I would expect eating your baked apple the next day should be fine.

I would not hold them much longer than that, though, as the cooking helps bring out moisture which will foster growth of molds over time.